# Is there any way to check whether export is in progress in report viewer in c#

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I am using Report viewer in my WPF application.I wanted to know whether export to excel is in progress or not. I have to close my window automatically once the export is completed.

Comment: Hi, are you exporting manually by code or report viewer control does that for you

Comment: I am using report viewer's in-built export functionality

Comment: you can try using different events ReportRefresh, ReportExport. Check whether is it called after export completed!   [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer_events(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: ReportRefresh, ReportExport will not work